# Searchbar to search multiple Strings

Tags: macos, swiftui

I would like to use the search bar to filter the following data.

[image]

[image]

I also used bindings and identifications, so it got pretty complex pretty quickly. I would be grateful for any help. All of the code is below.

```
import SwiftUI

// First navigationbar
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondaryView()) {
                    Text("Customer")
                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 12)
            SecondaryView()
        }
    }
}

// Second navigationbar
struct SecondaryView: View {
    @State private var search = ""
    @State private var customerData = [
        ListView("1035", "John", "Doe"),
        ListView("10213", "Jane", "Smith")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    TextField("Search ", text: $search)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 3)
                ForEach($customerData) { $i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CustomerView(number: $i.number, firstName: $i.firstName, lastName: $i.lastName)) {
                        Text(i.number) +
                        Text(" ") +
                        Text(i.firstName)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray) +
                        Text(" ") +
                        Text(i.lastName)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Id for second navigationbar
struct ListView: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    init(_ number: String, _ firstName: String, _ lastName: String) {
        self.number = number
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}

// Third view (empty)
struct CustomerView: View {
    @Binding var number: String
    @Binding var firstName: String
    @Binding var lastName: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I used the following line for the search, but since I now want to filter out several words from an array with bindings and ids, this method no longer works.

```
ForEach(customerNumber.filter({ (i: String) -> Bool in return i.hasPrefix(searchText) || searchText == "" }), id: \.self) { i in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want it in the titlebar, do that:

```js
import SwiftUI
struct SearchBar : UIViewRepresentable {
   @Binding var text : String
   
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, 
                  textDidChange searchText: String) {
      text = searchText
   }
}
func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Cordinator {
      return Cordinator(text: $text)
   }
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) 
   -> UISearchBar {
   
      let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
      searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
      return searchBar
   }
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UISearchBar, 
                context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
       uiView.text = text
    }
}
```

```js
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
let names = [“Raju”, “Ghanshyam”, “Baburao Ganpatrao Apte”,   “Anuradha”, “Kabira”, “Chaman Jhinga”, “Devi Prasad”, “Khadak Singh”]
@State private var searchTerm : String = “”
var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
         List {
            SearchBar(text: $searchTerm)
            
            ForEach(self.names.filter{
              self.searchTerm.isEmpty ? true :    $0.localizedStandardContains(self.searchTerm)
}, id: \.self) { name in
   Text(name)
              }
         }
          .navigationBarTitle(Text(“Search Bar”))
}
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
      ContentView()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```js
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SearchViewModel()
    @State private var query = ""

    let suggestions: [String] = [
        "Swift", "SwiftUI", "Obj-C"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List() {
               // Your code..
            }
            .navigationTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $query) {
                ForEach(suggestions, id: \.self) { suggestion in
                    Text(suggestion)
                        .searchCompletion(suggestion)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: query) { newQuery in
                async { await viewModel.search(matching: query) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use .searchable because it appears in the titlebar .. :/

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).